# Read array of array with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an array of arrays of numbers of the following structure (spaces and line returns are preserved):

```
[
  [
    123,
    1.989
  ],
  [
    456,
    4.343
  ],
...
]
```

The size of the data is 12Gb.

Is it possible to read it as a DataFrame of 2 columns: Integer and Double? So far I have tried to read it as JSON (creates only one corrupted record) and as text - it reads each line individually, and I am not sure if the order of lines is guaranteed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What format is the data stored as?

Comment: It is saved as json object using python's json.dump(indent=2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored as a python list, you can do the following.

```
arr = [ 
        [74, 0.072],
        [84, 0.538],
        [1, 0.051],
        [2, 0.103],
        [14, 0.232],
        [79, 0.98],
        [61, 0.645],
        [11, 0.825],
        [88, 0.49],
        [71, 0.86]
        ]

from pyspark.sql import types

arr_schema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('int_name', types.IntegerType()),
        types.StructField('float_name', types.FloatType()),
        ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]) for i in range(len(arr))],
        arr_schema)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data is 12Gb and stored in S3. How do I read it from there in the first place?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. This might help though https://towardsai.net/p/programming/pyspark-aws-s3-read-write-operations